# Extract full year from Quarter value using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where there is a column from where I would like to extract the full year.

```
**Data**

ID     Qtr
AA     Q123
AA     Q123
BB     Q226
BB     Q327

**Desired**

ID    Qtr   Year
AA    Q123  2023
AA    Q123  2023
BB    Q226  2026
BB    Q327  2027

**Doing**

df1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(df, '%YY').date()
```

However, the quarter is not an actual date, still researching on how to perform this.
Any suggestion is helpful

Comment: Does the `Qtr` column just contain strings? If so, try `df['Year'] = ('20' + df['Qtr'].str[2:]).astype(int)`

Comment: @It_is_Chris it is classified as an object when I run the dtypes, however, yes it is a string essentially

Comment: I will try, thank you. Ok so this would be a concatenation and removal of the first 2 values @It_is_Chris

Comment: Yes, that is correct. `df['Qtr'].str[2:])` removes the first two characters from the string.

Answer (score 1):

[@It_is_Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9177877/it-is-chris) talked through the simplest way, which is just string slicing. The following method actually creates datetimes. This is slower, but more powerful if you need to do anything more complex with your dates.

`> df`

```
    ID  Qtr
0   AA  Q123
1   AA  Q123
2   BB  Q226
3   BB  Q327
```

###### 1. Extract two digit year

`df["Qtr"].str.slice(2)`

```
0    23
1    23
2    26
3    27
```

###### 2. Convert into datetimes

`> pd.to_datetime(df["Qtr"].str.slice(2), format="%y")`

```
0   2023-01-01
1   2023-01-01
2   2026-01-01
3   2027-01-01
```

###### 3. Extract the year

`> pd.to_datetime(df["Qtr"].str.slice(2), format="%y").dt.year`

```
0    2023
1    2023
2    2026
3    2027
```

###### 4. Reassign

```
> df["Year"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Qtr"].str.slice(2), format="%y").dt.year
> df
```

```
    ID  Qtr Year
0   AA  Q123    2023
1   AA  Q123    2023
2   BB  Q226    2026
3   BB  Q327    2027
```